How can I dynamically create convolutional layers in a PyTorch model based on image content using self-supervision?
I’m working on a self-supervised learning project and need to create a convolutional neural network (CNN) in PyTorch where the number of convolutional layers and their kernel sizes are dynamically adjusted based on the content of the input image. The idea is to analyze the complexity of the image (e.g., detecting textures, edges, etc.) and adjust the architecture accordingly to improve efficiency and performance.
Here’s the challenge:
I want to implement a self-supervised module that learns to predict the optimal number of layers and the kernel size for each layer based on the image's features. Essentially, this model will evolve during training, adapting its structure without human intervention.
For example:

If an image has a lot of fine details or textures, the network should
automatically decide to have more layers with smaller kernel sizes.
If the image is simple with large objects, fewer layers with larger
kernels should be used.

This requires a few things:

Feature analysis module: A module that dynamically analyzes image
features (like texture complexity).
Layer generator: Based on the output of the feature analysis,
dynamically adjust the number of convolutional layers, their kernel sizes, and maybe even their filter counts.
Self-supervised learning loop: The model should learn to adjust
these parameters during training without labels, using some
self-supervised signal.

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models

class DynamicCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DynamicCNN, self).__init__()
        
        # feature analysis module
        self.feature_analyzer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        
        # convolutional layers that should be dynamically generated
        self.conv_layers = []
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # Feature analysis (this is where the dynamic analysis will go)
        features = self.feature_analyzer(x)
        
        # Dynamically generate layers based on analysis (to be implemented)
        for layer in self.conv_layers:
            x = F.relu(layer(x))
        
        # ... rest of the network ...
        
        return x

My questions:

How would you design the feature analysis module to determine the
optimal depth and kernel sizes of the CNN based on the content of
the image?
What’s the best approach to dynamically creating layers
during training? Is it possible to efficiently handle this with
PyTorch’s autograd system, and how could this architecture evolve
during backpropagation?
What kind of self-supervised signal would
you recommend to guide the model in learning the best structure for
each image?

I’m really interested in hearing your thoughts on this, especially when it comes to designing a system that can intelligently and dynamically adjust its architecture without labels.

The process you've outlined won't work. If implemented, it would randomly add untrained layers during inference. If you want a learned process for architecture design, look into neural architecture search which runs the architecture search loop outside the model training loop. Alternatively, since you seem to know the image -> architecture relationship you want, you can explicitly train those models separately and train a classifier to route images to those models
